# Sahih Bukhari and sahih muslim

Tags: hadith, books

I have bought sahih Bukhari hadith book and is sahih Muslim the duplicate or repeating of sahih Bukhari hadith?

Comment: These are two different collections of hadith from two different people so technically it is not a duplicate but a lot of the same content does appear in both.

Comment: Both texts are available online for free so you can see for yourself. There are common ahadith between them but there are also reports which are in Bukhari and not in Muslim and vice versa.

Comment: Honestly this is a very basic and googlable question. Sahih al-Bukhari is a book of imam al-Bukhari and Sahih Muslim is a book of imam Muslim, both did a huge effort to collect sahih hadith. And both had common teachers (sources) while Muslim also was a student of al-Bukhari. Both books have around 2000 ahadith in common and in the sum have gathered 4000 of 4300 sahih narrations.